# How to limit VM's network which is running by VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, network-interface, limit, bandwidth

I have hypervisor where Ubuntu Server 18.04 is installed and VM where Ubuntu Server 22.04 is installed.

VM has access to the internet through Host-only adapter. It means I have `vboxnet0` interface on the host. I tried to install wondershaper on both host and VM and try it at first on the host, then on VM.

I tried to limit VM's network on the host

```bash
root@ubuntu-server-1804-hypervisor:~# wondershaper vboxnet0 100000 100000
```

And then to check speedtest on VM:

```bash
root@ubuntu-server-2204-fastpanel:~# speedtest

   Speedtest by Ookla

      Server: [HIDDEN] - [HIDDEN] (id: [HIDDEN])
         ISP: [HIDDEN]
Idle Latency:     3.08 ms   (jitter: 0.08ms, low: 3.03ms, high: 3.14ms)
    Download:   108.42 Mbps (data used: 82.4 MB)                                   
                  3.33 ms   (jitter: 0.75ms, low: 2.38ms, high: 9.15ms)
      Upload:    11.97 Mbps (data used: 20.1 MB)                                   
                  3.22 ms   (jitter: 0.73ms, low: 2.10ms, high: 23.76ms)
 Packet Loss:     0.0%
  Result URL: [HIDDEN]
root@ubuntu-server-2204-fastpanel:~#
```

It's okay if wondershape didn't limit download how it should be. But upload was dropped to 5-20 Mbps.

Then I tried to limit eth0 on VM itself and the result is even more weird

```bash
root@ubuntu-server-2204-fastpanel:~# wondershaper eth0 100000 100000
root@ubuntu-server-2204-fastpanel:~# speedtest

   Speedtest by Ookla

      Server: [HIDDEN] - [HIDDEN] (id: [HIDDEN])
         ISP: [HIDDEN]
Idle Latency:     3.04 ms   (jitter: 0.60ms, low: 2.17ms, high: 4.04ms)
    Download:    43.61 Mbps (data used: 66.1 MB)                                   
                  2.43 ms   (jitter: 2.17ms, low: 1.39ms, high: 207.96ms)
      Upload:   496.98 Mbps (data used: 869.0 MB)                                  
                  8.79 ms   (jitter: 4.35ms, low: 2.46ms, high: 38.23ms)
 Packet Loss:     0.0%
  Result URL: [HIDDEN]
root@ubuntu-server-2204-fastpanel:~#
```

It dropped download to 40-50 mbps and almost didn't limit upload. Just slightly